# regex to fix csv quotes

Tags: python, regex, scala, csv, regex-negation

I have a simple csv with quotes, something like:

> "something","something","something","something",...

BUT, sometimes I get csv with

> "something","som"ething"","s"omething",...

and I wanted to create a regex that will fix this problem, does someone have something to offer?

something that will take out everything out from the string that is not a number or text, but when I take out `"` I need to make sure its not the ones that bounds the string cause i need those..

so from `"som"ething"","s"ometh8 ing"` id expect => `"something","someth8 ing"`

im using scala but any solution will be great!

thanks!!

Comment: You may use `'"' + x.replace('"', '') + '"'` for each of the values

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use regex? A string replace would be a lot simpler.

Comment: What about correctly escaped quotes, e.g. `"a""b","cd"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple solution

A simple solution in Scala:

```scala
scala> val input = """"som"ething"","s"ometh8 ing""""
input: String = "som"ething"","s"ometh8 ing"

scala> val values = input.split("\",\"").map(_.filter(c => c.isLetterOrDigit || c.isWhitespace))
values: Array[String] = Array(something, someth8 ing)

scala> val output = values.mkString("\"", "\",\"", "\"")
output: String = "something","someth8 ing"
```

Assuming you never have `","` inside your values, but if you do then there's no way to fix your CSV unambiguously anyway.

This isn't the most optimal solution speed or memory-wise, but it's short and simple.

## EDIT: Regex solution

In case you really want some regexes, enjoy:

```scala
scala> input.replaceAll("""(^"|"$|","|[\p{IsAlphabetic}\p{Digit}\p{Space}])|.""", "$1")
res17: String = "something","someth8 ing"
```

This tries to match `"` at the beginning or end of input OR `","` anywhere else OR any of your approved characters. If any of these match, it goes to the first capturing group. Otherwise, it matches any character (`.`), but doesn't capture it in a group, so the first group stays empty. Then, the matched substring is replaced with `$1`, which is the content of the first capturing group.

I still think the first solution is cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
csv_string = '"something","som"ething"","s"omething"'
for each_str in re.findall(r'(.*?)[\,\n]', csv_string):
    print(re.sub(r'\"', '', each_str)
```

add a line feed, to the end of the string so that you can include the last part of the string in re.findall